# Nemo replaces Nautilus on Unity and Gnome Shell session after I installed latest version of Cinnamon

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, nautilus, cinnamon

I installed the latest version of Cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04 and now Nemo replaces Nautilus when I choose Unity or Gnome Shell session. When I start Unity I have to restart the session for 3-4 times to restore Nautilus, on the contrary when I choose Gnome Shell Nautilus never works, it remains Nemo. Is there a way to have Nemo only on Cinnamon session and not on Unity and Gnome Shell too or the only solution is to remove Cinnamon? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try asking the developers of Cinnamon that decided forking something as core as Nautilus was a good idea.